# The price id of 16 and 32 IP address primary subnet on the vlan for softlayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When I try to place an order to order a vlan with the primary subnet using the code below, for the subnet price id, I specify it as 28842, which represents 32 static IP address. However, the actual subnet associated with the vlan I get is an 8 IP address. So I want to know why this consistency happened, as I specify 32, but actually get 8.

I contact the SL support, who replied me that the primary subnet on the vlan is set to be 8 by default. But if I specify to be 32, why I still get a default one? Also if I want to get a 16 and 32 primary(**not portable**) subnet, what's the correct price id I should feed in? Thanks.

Code:

```
product_order= {
        "complexType" => 'SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Vlan',
        'hardware' => "",
        "quantity" => 1,
        "location"=>datacenter,
        "packageId"=>0,
        "name" => vlan_name,
        "prices"=>[
            {"id"=> vlan_type},
            {"id"=> subnet_size **(here I feed 28842)**},
            {"id"=> 32082}],
        "stepId" => 7,
        "routerId" => router,
        # "description" => desc
    }

    placeOrder(product_order)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the issue you mentioned. On the other hand, I was able to order a Vlan without problems using only item prices for **Vlan_type** and (Primary) **Subnet's size** with 32 ip addresses.

It looks like this issue is due to item price 32082, I don't know why you are using it but I recommend remove it if there isnt any particular reason to add it.

Comment: This part of code is written by my colleague, I'm working to add some new features to this. So I don't know why the item price 32082 is used there. However, I check the price 32082 refers to a International Services, has nothing to do with vlan type or subnet size, why do you think this will cause the problem here? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, this item price belongs to Category: Premium and the description you've mentioned above, however the Portal doesn't make use of this item price when ordering.

Currently this particular issue has now been reported on SoftLayer, but meanwhile you may order normally and without problems as provided in the solution. If your colleague require to use this item price for some specific  reason, then you may submit a ticket for further assistance.